# Which are MVVM pattern features and extensions?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture, mvvm, viewmodel

Which are MVVM pattern features and extensions?
As I have noticed there are many MVVM frameworks out there, and all share the same concept, even though there are some differences. I won’t ask what the differences are, however I would like to create a general list of key features/extensions for MVVM pattern that will provide a good starting point when choosing between different frameworks or own created MVVM pattern .
Please explain the feature you are mentioning. For making the question clear I’ll start with my own knowledge. I’ll complete the list as I get answers.

**Patterns**

- ObservableCollection
- INotifyPropertyChanged
- ICommand
- Mediator
- Behaviours(System.Windows.Interactivity)

**Structure**

- Model
- ViewModel
- ModelView

Answer (score 0):

Behaviours(System.Windows.Interactivity) are very usefull when coding mvvm. there are a lot out there.